# I show the grades to each of my students using Google sheets and publishing them with the scripts editor. Can I do the same with Google app maker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Google announced that Apps Script UI service will be discontinued next July. At my school some teachers are using Google sheets gradebooks together with app scripts code to publish the grades as a webpage, so that each student can see only his/her grades. If next school year this is not going to work any more, we need to find a new way of doing the same. Google suggests using Google App maker.

Since I am a teacher and not a developer, I have no idea of how to use the App maker. I am ready to learn, though, if it is the best way to solve the problem.

But before I use a lot of the time I don't really have in learning to use a new tool, I would really appreciate if you could tell me that what we are doing with Apps Script can be done using the Google App maker.

I would be really grateful if you could show me the way to start migrating the script code to App maker.

This is a sample of the Google sheet we use as Gradebook:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Id3-5o6JpNJWkHWUjOSWaJ3PLRveOdYoAynURxzNYFE/edit?usp=sharing

This is the code we use in the Google sheets script editor:

```
//Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();

return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

app.close();
return app;
}

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Id3-5o6JpNJWkHWUjOSWaJ3PLRveOdYoAynURxzNYFE');//Put your spreadsheet key here
var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('StudentGrades');//Meta sheet name
var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName('logsheet');
var data = sh1.getDataRange().getValues();
var user = Session.getEffectiveUser()
Logger.log(user)

function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('English Grades - Teacher: Anna C');//App title
 if(!getcol(user)){
 var warn = app.createLabel().setWidth('400').setText("Your results are not available or your email is not in the list. Please contact your teacher.");
// if user is not in the list, warning + return
app.add(warn)
return app
      }
var grid = app.createGrid(data.length, 3).setWidth('900px').setBorderWidth(1).setCellPadding(6).setCellSpacing(6).setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse').setId('grid');
//Overall table styling
var text = app.createLabel(user).setWidth('250px');
var col = getcol(user)
grid.setWidget(0,1,text).setText(0, 0, 'ENGLISH RESULTS FOR');
for(n=1;n<data.length;++n){
     grid.setText(n, 0, string(data[n][0]));
     grid.setText(n, 1, string(data[n][1]));
     grid.setText(n, 2, string(data[n][col]));         

     //FIRST ROW HEADER (Dark blue background) - row 0
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(0, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'bold',color: "#fff",'background':'#384c80','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});

     //COURSE-JUNE-SEPTEMBER MARKS (Dark red background) - rows 288,294,298
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(250, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'bold',color: "#fff",'background':'#900202','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});

     //TERMS-TERM MARKS (Orange background) - rows 5,105,202,289,291,293
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(5, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'bold',color: "#fff",'background':'#ff953f','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});

     //SUMMER-1ST T MARKS (Orange bold font)
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(20, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'bold',color: "#ff953f",'background':'#fff','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});

     //DIMENSIONS MARKS (Dark blue bold font)
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(54, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'bold',color: "#384c80",'background':'#fff','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});

     //Level B green exercises (Dark green font)
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(30, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'normal',color: "#009A46",'background':'#fff','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});

     //Level A red exercises (Red font)
     grid.setRowStyleAttributes(45, {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",'textAlign':'left','fontWeight':'normal',color: "#ff0000",'background':'#fff','border':'1px solid #c0c0c0'});
   }
   app.add(grid);
   return app
}

function string(value){
Logger.log(typeof(value))
if (typeof(value)=='string'){return value};// if string then don't do anything
if (typeof(value)=='number'){return Utilities.formatString('%.2f',value)};// if number then format with 2 decimal
if (typeof(value)=='object'){return Utilities.formatDate(value, Session.getTimeZone(), "MM-dd")};//object >> date in this case, format month/day
return 'error'
}

function getcol(mail){
if(data[0].toString().indexOf(mail.toString())!=-1){
for(zz=1;zz<data[0].length;++zz){
if(data[0][zz] == mail){var colindex=zz;break}
}
return colindex
}
return false
}
```

And this is what our students see after they log in with their gmail account. They see their results as a webpage. (I have created a sample student's mail so that I can show you what they see).

Go to 
https://script.google.com/a/jverdaguer.com/macros/s/AKfycbwGmZr-UVw1hAtkyQEM8mqax1UkiKEGrF1wCOE/exec 
and log in with the mail samplestudent@jverdaguer.com and the password sstudent2018

Comment: I think the main draw back you may have with App Maker is that your students would need to have an email address within the same domain as where the application is published from. Additionally, if using Google Cloud SQL as your database then there will be some additional charges incurred. However, you could bypass Cloud SQL and just set a data model to a calculated model, which will call your server script connecting to the spreadsheet. Otherwise, I think for something as simple as grades updating and viewing by students the learning curve would not be steep at all.

Comment: All our students have an email address within our domain, so that would not be a problem. Paying for the Google Cloud SQL would.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/), the Google Apps Documentation states:`Deprecated. The UI service was deprecated on December 11, 2014. To create user interfaces, use the HTML service instead.`

The [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) is alive and well with no indications of deprecation or sunset in the documentation.  There is also  a [UI Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) which allows you to create alerts, prompts and custom dialog and is available through SpreadsheetApp and DocumentApp and possibly other ways that I'm not familiar with.

There is no indication that Google Apps Script is going away.  I use Google Apps script a lot in App Maker.

I agree that it would be a good idea to begin replacing the use of any deprecated functionality as soon as possible.

Comment: Google sent us this email: "We’re writing to let you know that the Apps Script UI Service, which was deprecated on December 11, 2014, will be discontinued on July 15, 2019. Any projects using Apps Script UI Service will cease to function from July 15. While there is no direct migration process for existing UI Service projects, Google App Maker is a new tool which can be used to create rich visual applications in G Suite and you can create similar UI applications using that tool." So we understand that we need to make changes to keep offering the same service to our students after july 15th.

Comment: It seems easier to show the grades using the HtmlService code rather than using the App maker and paying for a Google Cloud SQL. Could someone give me some hints on how to update my UI Service code to HtmlService code?